# Make Toolbar go to very bottom

Tags: android, android-layout

So I'm trying to create sort of a mirror to the Instagram app in terms of it's bottom bar. So I guess what I'm trying to ask is if this is even possible? Whenever I create a toolbar in my own mock app it'll leave a slight space between the bottom of the toolbar and the bottom of the app.

So all in all is there a way to make the toolbar go to the very bottom or am I going at this wrong?

(I'd post pictures but I need 10 rep :( )

Comment: are their margin and padding zero?

Comment: @JKPark Setting Margin/Padding to zero still leaves a small space between the system bar and the toolbar I'm using.

Maybe this picture will help visualize http://i.imgur.com/VWxsI2i.png

Comment: do you mean the blue space?

Comment: @JKPark No, that is just the border of my emulator. Im talking about how the toolbar will leave space between the sides of the app and between the system bar and the toolbar.

Comment: Android 4.0 or later will automatically create a margin around the widget. ([link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout))  what is your version of AVD?